# Suppress warning: The Swift file cannot be processed by a Copy Bundle Resources build phase

Tags: swift, cocoapods, ios12, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have an app that uses a Swift framework that contains an intentdefinition file.  I use CocoaPods to manage/distribute my frameworks, so, in order for Siri to successfully find the app and extension so that she can respond, I needed to add a "Build Phases"/"Copy Bundle Resources" step that copies the intentdefinition file from the framework into the app's main bundle.

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52613170/2941876) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613171/2941876) for more background about this question.

The app and extension are working properly, now, but at compile time I get warnings for each intent:

> "The Swift file
>   '.../DerivedSources/IntentDefinitionGenerated/*Intents/*Intent.swift'
>   cannot be processed by a Copy Bundle Resources build phase"

While this statement is true, it is not relevant in this case, since the framework will process the files.

How can I suppress this warning?

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760452/xcode-generated-coredata-files-cannot-be-processed-by-copy-bundle-resources-buil/54046043#54046043. It is similar to yours, although it specifically deals with a coreData file issue rather than an intent file issue. I am not sure if your problem relates or not.

Comment: If the Intent file is not copied into the bundle then the Intent functionality does not work (see the link referenced in the question).  By adding the "Build Phases"/"Copy Bundle Resources" step, everything works, but I then continuously see the warnings with each compile...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the files mentioned in the warning are there in `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources` Simply remove from there and warning will be gone.
[image]